# A request to open my self answered question on Lückentexte

Tags: discussion

this is in regards to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75058/tips-for-doing-l%C3%BCckentests-cloze-tests/75059#75059). I think it would be in best interest of the site to keep this question open.

To begin, we all find this site in different ways. I for one found this site when I wanted help with translating sentences that I Found on duolingo in German to English. Now, this I find to have generated a bit of what I consider now to be "poor quality questions" on my account, eventually, I think, I've asked a few good questions here and there.

In the case of Lueckentests, it is a challenge that many people who are interested in coming to Germany must overcome. I think, if we had a guide for this, it would attract people to this site, make them long term users and then later maybe they will ask high quality questions.

For the case of the preparatory course that I am trying for, more than thousand students come from all over the world to write exam in Germany in hopes of getting a chance in this course. Some of which will probably be interested in studying the language long term and contributing.

Having them drawn to this place would be really nice for the long term health of this site in my opinion.

Mit freundlichen grußen